# Cannot install specific projects in monorepo (RushJS) on BitBucket

Tags: bitbucket, rush

I have a monorepo project that is using Rush which each projects can be either both frontend or backend dependencies. Some projects are used by both frontend and backend while some are for only either. Thus, I only want to install each specific dependency on the monorepo.

I first tried to install on the frontend using Git clone url with something like this:
https://bitbucket.myprivateorg.mycountry/scm/#.git/<monorepo_project_subdirectory>.

I also tried some other combinations but of course it did not work. I have looked it up, and I noticed that npm lacks this support. However, some solutions that I saw was GitPkg but it only works for GitHub. All my repos are strictly on BitBucket only.

Is there any equivalent of GitPkg for BitBucket?

Comment: *Thus, I only want to install each specific dependency FROM the monorepo.
*https://bitbucket.myprivateorg.mycountry/scm/[project]#[version].git/<monorepo_project_subdirectory>

Comment: I am looking for the same solution